# How can I remove Bootstrap from my Angular project?

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

I am attempting to use Material Design Bootstrap (MDB) in my Angular project. However, when I use an angular bootstrap component, it seems standard bootstrap interferes with the styling.

[image]

Whats the best way to fully remove bootstrap from my angular project so my components are only styled by angular bootstrap?

**Edit**

*angular.json*

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

*package.json*,

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.2",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.52",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^7.5.2",
    "atom": "^1.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "terminal": "^0.1.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

Comment: Can you upload the package.json and angular.json content for me

Comment: Yes, I've added them

Comment: That's weird can you search all the file to see is there any reference to bootstrap

Comment: @Ethernetz can you check the whole project for the reference of `bootstrap.min.css` or `bootstrap.css`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**First :** Remove bootstrap dependency From your `package.json`as shown below for example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.1",   <-------REMOVE THIS
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
```

**Second** : Remove the bootstrap url from `angular.json`, if you have placed it under styles section like as shown below

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" <--- REMOVE THIS
],
```

**Third** : Check and Remove any bootstrap references explicitly imported in `styles.css` or any other files remotely or locally like as shown below

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: Thanks, I was importing it in styles.css as well.

Answer (score 10):

`npm uninstall bootstrap --no-save`

also remove the reference you added in angular.json under styles which points bootstrap.min.css

```
"styles": [
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"src/styles.css"
 ],
```

Comment: In addition to this, I removed bootstrap  entry from package-lock.json too

Answer (score 2):

For me, I have the Angular project generated by Visual Studio. After remove all bootstrap references, I need to rebuild the angular project *ng build* in order for the project to work correctly. Just throw this one out in case some one needs it.

Answer (score 0):

follow the answer 1 if you want to understand how angular and or you are a beginner to angular/front-end-development because doing things manually for the first time are very helpful for the future,

if you are not a beginner and want to save time then just paste
npm uninstall bootstrap --no-save

my answer is for all the angular developers

Comment: This is already given by the accepted answer and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56147263/5468463. SO is not a forum, we do not discuss and each answer needs to be useful