# How to remove bootstap from angular project?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular9

When my angular project run i see that `_reboot.scss` is already uploaded. It overwrites styles of angular material.

I have tried to remove it using following steps:

1. npm uninstall bootstrap
2. Remove links from package.json
3. Remove links from angular.json

Is there any ways for removing bootstrap completely from my project?

**angular.json**

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "AngularDesk": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/AngularDesk",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [

            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AngularDesk:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "AngularDesk:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AngularDesk:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "AngularDesk:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "AngularDesk:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "AngularDesk"
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-desk",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you Show your `styles.css` file as well ?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56145438/6356369

Comment: Try removing node modules and install again. If still not working try clearing browser cache.

Comment: I've already tried clear my styles.css file and clear browser cache. Also I saw suggested link before posting my quesion. As you can see in my configuration files links for bootstrap does not exist.
I've tried reinstall node modules,but problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

After steps you have done ,check and remove any bootstrap references explicitly imported in your files :

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```