# Need to Roll Back - Installed Angular powered Bootstrap and everything is thrown off

Tags: angular

I started out with Angular Material library for my project and then installed Angular powered Bootstrap. Geez...it blew up everything and all the components look extremely sideways now. What is a good way to roll back the changes?

command used to install - ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

I looked at this post [How can I remove Bootstrap from my Angular project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145339/how-can-i-remove-bootstrap-from-my-angular-project) and reverted most of the changes accordingly. But this seems really manual and could easily go wrong imo. So I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the command you used to install bootstrap?

Comment: @ShafiqJetha hi, it was ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Comment: Start by removing the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, bootstrap and @angular/localize packages from the dependencies section of the package.json file, then do npm install and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.
issue `npm uninstall @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
as far as i can tell, it has countered `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`